# How do I check my opening balance in Quicken 2014?

Tags: banking, corporate-acquisition, quicken

My Quicken account is way out of balance, and I think this all started a couple of years ago when [my old bank](https://www.vistbank.com/) decided it would be fun to delete the payee names on all of my old transactions on a sync, during their merger.  Needless to say, they're no longer my bank.

Anyway I'm trying to get it back together starting with following instructions from the following [post](https://qlc.intuit.com/questions/767098-why-quicken-is-not-showing-my-true-balance), and the first instruction is `Whether the account opening balance is correct - and correct it if not.`

Where can I check the opening balance of my accounts in Quicken?  Is it the first transaction in the register or something more complicated than that?  Also, is it generally possible to find out the open balance from your bank, to ensure that it is correct?

Comment: Usually there is a transaction at the very beginning of the account register in Quicken that is called "Opening account balance".  This is what I see in Quicken 2012, don't know about 2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, the opening balance in a Quicken 2014 account is simply how much is in the account at the point you want to start tracking.

If you started tracking an account at the beginning of 2014 (say) then your opening balance in your Quicken account would be the closing balance on your December 2013 statement.  Every transaction after that is an adjustment to the opening balance.